# Regexp - indexing

Tags: tcl

I am totally new in using regexp for TCL but I have some large data need to be filter using regexp.

Example a compiler compiled a huge of data but luckily it is divided into groups,

```
-I- Data1 compiled

result_1

-I- Data2 compiled

result_2

result_3

result_4

-I- Data3 compiled

result_5

-I- Data4 compiled

result_6
```

So now I want to grab any results (it can be multiple results) within Data2. I could use "-I- Data2 compiled" as an indicator to start grab but it need to stop at "-I- Data3 compiled".

I used this but obviously wrong, `regexp {-I- Data2 compiled.*-I-} $all_data output_1`

It kept return,

```
-I- Data2 compiled

result_2

result_3

result_4

-I- Data3 compiled

result_5

-I-
```

So my question is does it possible to start grab when detect "-I- Data2" and stop grab result by the next "-I-" ?

Answer (score 1):

For a small file, regex would be ok to use and in which case I would suggest using the following regexp:

```
set f [open "input.txt" r]
set data [read $f]
close $f

regexp -- {-I- Data2 compiled\s*(.*?)\s*-I- Data3 compiled} $data -> results
puts $results
# => This will give you the lines you're looking for
```

If the data is big, I would suggest rather reading the file line by line and output in another file so you don't slow down your system and possibly overload your system's memory:

```
set f [open "input.txt" r]
set o [open "output.txt" w]
# If 0 will not output anything, 1 will
set capture 0

while {[gets $f line] != -1} {
  # Ignore empty lines
  if {$line == ""} {continue}

  if {$capture} {
    if {[string first "-I- Data3 compiled" $line] > -1} {break}
    puts $o $line
  }

  if {[string first "-I- Data2 compiled" $line] > -1} {
    # Since we saw "-I- Data2 compiled", start capture next line
    set capture 1
  }
}

close $f
close $o
```

Comment: If the data is _truly_ big, it belongs in something better than a text file. Try SQLite…

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
set all_data "-I- Data1 compiled

result_1

-I- Data2 compiled

result_2

result_3

result_4

-I- Data3 compiled

result_5

-I- Data4 compiled

result_6"

#puts $all_data

#Using the flag '--' to treat the hyphens as a literal hyphens instead of regex range
#Also using sub-match to extract the exact data between Data 2 and Data 3 

puts [ regexp -- {-I- Data2 compiled\n(.*)\n-I- Data3 compiled} $all_data match result]

#In the regexp, '\n' is may not necessary. But using it for printing convention

#Variable 'match' will hold the whole content including '-I- Data2 compiled' and '-I- Data3 compiled'
puts $result
```

Output :

```
result_2

result_3

result_4
```